# How to find column count in a TableHeaderRow with only table id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a situation where I want to make a generic codebehind function to show a message row that spans the whole table. I have previously passed the Table object and the number of columns so that it could set the column span, but this is somewhat error prone as we sometimes add new columns and I have to update the column count numbers for the messages.

There doesn't seem to be any column count in the Table object and neither any way to get the TableHeaderRow that has been added in the aspx file. I'd like to avoid having to add id's to all the TableHeaderRow's as well.

Comment: if you are using a gridview, off the top of my head you could possibly add to the rowDataBound event, determine if the rowType = datacontrolrowtype.header, then count for each tablecell in headerRow.cells (declare headerRow as GridViewRow = e.row).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work (assuming the TableHeaderRow is the first child of the Table):

```
int j = 0;
foreach (Control current in tableId.Controls[0].Controls)
{
    if (current.ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableHeaderCell")
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```